# Calculate polygon area in vector grid QGIS

Tags: polygon, area, vector-grid

I have a polygon layer in QGIS (building outlines) and I made a grid over this layer using the MMQGIS function. I want to calculate the area of the building outlines in each grid cell (so it becomes another column in the grid cell layer).

Any ideas?

It's all in vector.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression on the grid layer and replace `building_layer_name` with the name of your layer containing the polygons of the buildings:

```
    area ( 
        intersection (
            $geometry, 
            collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('building_layer_name',$geometry))
        )
    )
```

*The expression used on the grid layer to create a label, indicating the area each cell overlaps with the building (2x2 m grid):*

[image]